# How to do a fast numerical computation of an oscillatory integral including $\operatorname{HeunC}$ function using Mathematica?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, maple, mathematica, oscillatory-integral

I am trying to numerically compute the following integral in Mathematica

$$\int_{1}^{1000} dx \,(x+2)e^{-2Ia(x+2)}\operatorname{HeunC}[-4Ib,-4Ib,1+4Ib,1,-4Ib,-x/2]$$

where $\operatorname{HeunC}$ is the [confluent Heun function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeunC.html). Mathematica can numerically compute this integral for the known values of $a$ and $b$. There are two problems here: When I increase the value of $a$ and $b$, the integral becomes highly oscillatory and it takes a long time to be computed. Also, even for the small value of $a$ and $b$, Mathematica spends a long time to compute this integral when the upper bound is $1000$, but it is pretty fast when I decrease the upper bound. Could you please help me with this problem?

Comment: This is better suited for https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions. You should include your code snippet so users there can address.

Comment: Please specify concrete problematic values of $a$ and $b$. Is $I = \sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: As an example, $a=10$ , $b=20$. Yes $I=\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: I have seen several questions of your, some with quite good answers, but you never accept them. Do they address you problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like HeunC was introduced in *Mathematica* only recently and may have implementation issues.

For shortness let's introduce
$$
F(x) = \operatorname{HeunC}(-4ib, -4ib, 1+4ib, 1,-4ib; -x/2)
$$

Evaluating it with `MachinePrecision` gives completely wrong results (obtained with https://www.wolframcloud.com/):

```
F[b_,x_] = HeunC[-4I b,-4I b,1+4I b,1,-4I b,-x/2];
F[10,500.]
-2.333438484634705*^4219+4.27023838819976*^4218 I
F[10,500.`1000]
0.00398375247818748....-0.0000498007848027014.... I
F[1,500.]
-1.84935*^270-1.79429*^266 I
F[1,500.`1000]
0.0039527529500429...-0.00049881082215... I
```

Plotting the function for small $x$ suggests that its absolute value monotonicaly decreases and never exceeds 1, so values with $10^{4219}$ magnitude are obviously wrong. I guess this leads to slow (and simply wrong) numerical integration in your case.

One of the possible solutions is to implement HeunC by yourself. We know that HeunC is a solution to
$$
y''(z) + \left(\frac{\gamma}{z} + \frac{\delta}{z-1} + \epsilon\right) y'(z) + \frac{\alpha  z - q}{z(z-1)} y(z) = 0\\
y(0) = 1
$$
In your case
$$
q = \alpha = \epsilon = -4ib\\
\gamma = 1 + 4ib\\
\delta = 1\\
z = -\frac{x}{2}
$$
Rewriting the equation in terms of $F$, $b$ and $x$ gives:
$$
F''(x) + \left(
\frac{1+4ib}{x} + \frac{1}{x+2} + 2ib
\right) F'(x) + \frac{2ib}{x} F(x) = 0\\
F'(0) = 1
$$

The problem is that you cannot just take this equation and ask *Mathematica* to solve it numerically. This is because

- this second order equation has only one initial condition,
- the point $x = 0$ is a singularity.

The former is a consequence of the latter. The usual solution of the problem is to step a bit away from the $x=0$ and to start numerical integration from $x=x_0 > 0$. Anyway, to start integration from $x = x_0$ one needs initial conditions, both for $F(x_0)$ and $F'(x_0)$.

One possibility is to ask *Mathematica* for them, since we know that $F(x)$ may be expressed in terms of HeunC. Another approach is to use series expansion. The series expansion can be derived from the [expansion for HeunC](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.01007.pdf), or may be obtained quite easily from the equation itself ([Frobenius method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method)).

Assume that $F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$. We already know that $c_0 = 1$. Multiplying the equation with $x$ and taking limit when $x \to 0$ yields
$$
(1 + 4 ib) F'(0) + 2 i b F(0) = 0 \implies c_1 = F'(0) = -\frac{2ib}{1 + 4ib}
$$
Now let's multiply the equation with $x(x+2)$:
$$
(x^2+2x) F''(x) + \left(
2ib x^2 + (2 + 8ib) x + 2 + 8 ib
\right) F'(x) + (2ib x + 4) F(x) = 0
$$
Let's now plug $F(x) = \sum_n c_n x^n$ and collect the coefficients before $x^n$ term:
$$
n(n-1) c_n + 2(n+1) n c_{n+1} + 
2ib (n-1) c_{n-1} + (2 + 8ib) n c_n + (2 + 8ib) (n+1) c_{n+1} 
+ 2ib c_{n-1} + 4ib c_n = 0
$$
$$
\left[2(n+1) n + (2 + 8ib) (n+1)\right]c_{n+1} + 
\left[n(n-1) + (2 + 8ib) n + 4ib\right] c_n + 
\left[2ib(n-1) + 2ib\right] c_{n-1} = 0,\\
2 (n+1) (1 + 4ib + n) c_{n+1} + 
\left[n(n+1) + 4ib(1+2n)\right] c_n + 
2ib n c_{n-1} = 0.
$$
This is a three-terms recurrence for $c_n$ from which we may obtain as many $c_n$ as we need.
$$
c_{n+1} = -\frac{\left[n(n+1) + 4ib(1+2n)\right] c_n + 
2ib n c_{n-1}}{2 (n+1) (1 + 4ib + n)}
$$
From the theory of the confluent Heun's function it is known that the radius of convergence of its series at $z=0$ is $R = 1$. Since we use $x/2$ as its argument, the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$ should be equal to $2$. Numerical experiment agrees with it:

[image]

Here's a plot of $\frac{|c_n|}{|c_{n+1}|}$ which illustrate that the limit for $n \to \infty$ is 2.
We may take $x_0 = 1$ and expect that series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x_0^n$ converge fast enough for plactical usage. Estimating truncation error with the first neglected term gives us that $M=50$ terms are enough for double precision (16 digits).

Now we can obtain $F(x)$ numerically by solving the problem
$$
F''(x) + \left(
\frac{1+4ib}{x} + \frac{1}{x+2} + 2ib
\right) F'(x) + \frac{2ib}{x} F(x) = 0, \quad x \in [1, 1000]\\
F(1) = \sum_{n=0}^{50} c_n\\
F'(1) = \sum_{n=1}^{50} n c_n 
$$

To minimize computational problems arising from numerical integration of an (piecewise) numerical solution I suggest evaluating integral *in the same* ODE problem. This is achieved by expanding the ODE problem with an auxiliary equation
$$
J'(x) = (x+2)e^{-2Ia(x+2)} F(x)\\
J(1) = 0.
$$
It is clear that
$$
J(x) = \int_1^x (t+2)e^{-2Ia(t+2)} F(t) dt
$$
and we're interested in $J(1000)$ only. Combining the problems into single ODE guarantees that ODE integration grid will be the same as quadrature integration grid. This cannot be achieved by separate `NDSolve` + `NIntegrate` calls.

[Here's](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/0dccba27-bfba-4f87-a32a-05621fe0aa0d) an implementation of this method in a notebook. But be warned - `WorkingPrecision` stongly affects the result. Using `MachinePrecision` is very fast, but the relative error is about $10^{-5}$. Using `MachinePrecision=20` improves the result by an order of magnitude or two, but timing is much worse.

Comment: I wonder why such a detailed answer haven't got any upvotes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. Unfortunately, I just saw your answer.